# React Router throwing redirect warnings with TransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I am using React Router with React Transition Group to animate between routes. I have a problem when I use a `<Redirect />` component. The App works, but I get multiple warnings from React Router that reads:

> Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"

You can see it happen in this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly9l09m22q). Make sure to open the sandbox console and then enter a bad path (like codesandbox.io/abc).

I tried following the example they give in their docs (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions), but that does not include a Redirect. Is there a better way to use Redirect and Transitions to avoid the warnings?

Comment: Hmm, removing the `location` prop on the `Switch` seems to fix it for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/w7j1kk8m17

Comment: Hi @ChaseDeAnda unfortunately that breaks the animation. Without the `location` prop, the current route changes immediately. I slowed down the animation in my original sandbox to better illustrate. https://codesandbox.io/s/ly9l09m22q Watch the word that animates out when you click.

Comment: Well maybe that's your problem :) sounds like the `location` prop isn't updating immediately and is causing multiple redirects to fire off before it updates.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `location` is updating properly. If I log it out in the `render`, I see render called twice and two logs with the expected `location.path`, followed by 3 of the above warning. If I remove the TransitionGroup components, I still see those same two logs (and no warnings). Could you suggest a way to test your theory?

Comment: Here is my solution https://codesandbox.io/s/o9j8nqpx49 I removed `Redirect` and reorder the routes. It achieves the same behavior, but without redirect the URL.

Comment: Hi @FisNaN thanks for the idea, but our real world use case is more complex and contains several redirects. We aren't able to remove them all. I am hoping for a solution that allows us to use transitions and redirects together.

Comment: My point is that you don't have to `redirect` in `switch` component. If you order your router correctly, it normally just works fine. When you try to redirect from certain page to another, you can always call `redirect` inside component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue occurs when a `<Redirect>` mounts within the animation components.

Instead of wrapping your animation components around `<Switch>`, wrap the `<Route>`'s child component. (You may need to use the `<Route>`'s `render` prop vs its `component` prop.)

This approach eliminates the need to pass the `location` prop to `<Switch>` -- instead each `<CSSTransition/>` references `location`.

See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nn5r595joj

Comment: Works! Thanks for the help!